# VS2015: How to build using MSBuild 12.0?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have VS2015 (MSBuild 14.0) and VS2013 (MSBuild 12.0) installed. There reason for this is that I have a project I could **only** build using MSBuild **12.0**. I've already been trough [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397428.aspx), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985.aspx), and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796.aspx). I changed the project file to specify MSBuild 12.0, but I get the following error:

> Project file contains ToolsVersion="12.0". This toolset may be unknown
>   or missing, in which case you may be able to resolve this by
>   installing the appropriate version of MSBuild, or the build may have
>   been forced to a particular ToolsVersion for policy reasons. Treating
>   the project as if it had ToolsVersion="14.0". For more information,
>   please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=293424.

I know the tool set is not missing, it is installed here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0`.

I was hoping it would be something straight forward as changing `ToolsVersion=12.0` in my .csproj file.

Additionally, I work with a team, so ideally I'm looking for the least invasive solution. I prefer not to change registry values and such.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot. VS loads hard coded MSBuild version by default and there is no explicit setting to change.

Comment: But this is not the impression I got from MSDN docs. Can you point me to where this is specified?

Comment: Would be very interesting to hear why can you only build with msbuild 12.0?

Comment: @stijn long story short, one of the dependencies in the project is not compatible with MSBuild 15.0. It was even reported in Roslyn GitHub [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4924)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could not use Tools Version 12 in visual studio 2015 directly. MSDN says:

> "Starting in Visual Studio 2013, the MSBuild Toolset version is the
>   same as the Visual Studio version number. MSBuild defaults to this
>   Toolset within Visual Studio and on the command line, regardless of
>   the ToolSet version specified in project file. This behavior can be
>   overridden by using the /ToolsVersion flag. For more information, see
>   [Overriding ToolsVersion Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985.aspx)."

We can override the ToolsVersion Settings of Projects and Solutions by using command prompt:

```
msbuild.exe someproj.proj /tv:12.0
```

Besides, Guy Bolton King provided a Visual Studio extension to achieve it. Here is the the [extension repository](https://github.com/guyboltonking/set-toolsversion-extension) project on GitHub.

> Set-toolsversion-extension that temporarily sets the environment variable MSBUILDDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION for the duration of a build; the value to be used is read from a file .toolsversion in the same directory as the .sln file. The psake script reads the same .toolsversion file and passes the value to the /tv switch.

Please build the extension project and install the SetToolsVersion.vsix to visual studio.

**Note that**: 
Thanks @mbadawi23 for reminding that cleaned the solution, closed VS and opened it again after installed the extension and also need to add the .toolsversion.

Comment: The link you provided lists three options: _1. by using the /ToolsVersion switch. 2. by setting the ToolsVersion parameter on the MSBuild task. 3.     by setting the $(ProjectToolsVersion) property on a project._ My initial attempt is build within the IDE, so that leaves options 2, and 3 which are not working for me. It looks like I'm at that point that I need a build system such as Jenkins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it provided good knowledge. I was about to accept your, but using that extension did not help. The extension by Guy Bolton King, sets `MSBUILDDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION` environment variable successfully, but that does not have an effect on the build. I get this in the output window: `Setting MSBUILDDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION to 12.0` and in a following line I get this: `4>Building with tools version "14.0".` And at the end of the build I get this: `Restoring MSBUILDDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION`

Comment: Actually, I was able to get it to work. I was going to update my comment tonight.

Comment: It still took me a while to get it to work. Please add a link to the extension repository and update your answer on how to build the extension project and use the extension. What I had to do is after running vs2015 for the first time after I installed the extension, is I cleaned the solution closed vs and opened it again. Of course I had to add .toolsversion file.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I have updated my comments and answer. If you have any other complement, please add a comment! Thanks.